# Is there a connection between gluons and photons?

Tags: particle-physics, photons, mass, standard-model, gluons

I was wondering if there is any sort of connection between [a gluon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon) and a photon since they are both considered massless.

Comment: I don't think they share any properties outside of both being spin-1, but I'm not versed enough in particle physics to say more than that.

Comment: 0 mass, 0 electric charge are also properties that they share from memory.

Answer (score 12):

Gluons and photons are similar in the sense that they are both massless gauge bosons. They do, however, correspond to different gauge symmetries: photons arise due to $\mathrm{U}(1)$ symmetry, while gluons follow from $\mathrm{SU}(3)$. This leads to a different number of particles: there is only one photon, while there are eight different gluons, corresponding to the number of generators of the respective gauge group. Furthermore, gluons are electrically neutral, but they are charged with colour charges, allowing them to self-interact strongly and even form bound states (glueballs). Photons, on the other hand, are simply electrically neutral but do not carry any other charges.

Comment: @BrendonBruns You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

From the perspective of fundamental quantum field theory, gluons and photons are quite similar. Both of them are gauge bosons, meaning that their existence is required by a mathematical mechanism called local gauge invariance. However, as *particles*, there isn't any particular connection between them. For instance, there's no reason they both have to be massless. The properties they share (zero mass, zero electric charge, spin one, etc.) are more coincidental than anything else.

Comment: *"For instance, there's no reason they both have to be massless."*...I wouldn't really say that, since gauge invariance usually protects gauge bosons from aquiring mass. Massive gauge bosons only arise through some spontaneously broken symmetry, e.g. through the Higgs mechanism. Also, that both have *spin one* is a direct consequence of them being the quanta of a gauge connection, which is always a vector field/1-form.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "...gauge connection, which is always a vector field/1-form." Not necessarily, it could be, for example, a 2-form, which strings may coupled to. There are also gauge theories based on non-Abelian 2-forms. See also Gerbe gauge theory.

Comment: @JamalS: Alright, the proper thing is to say that all gauge theories in the ordinary QFT/SM setting are *1-gauge theories*. I meant no disrespect to higher gauge theory.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: That's fine, I don't study or practice higher gauge theory :)

Answer (score -2):

the 9th gluon of the U(3) symmetry is considered a photon. which makes the color symmetry su(3)

Comment: It would be great if you could explain this a bit more...